# How do you whitelist a specific domain for a specific content security policy directive, while having a less specific directive for other domains?

Tags: content-security-policy

I want to allow `unsafe-eval` for a `script-src` policy, but only for a specific domain.

For example, I only want scripts from `*.example.net` to be able to use `eval()`.

```
script-src 'unsafe-inline' *;script-src 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' *.example.net blob:;
```

The above does not work. How can I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I want to allow 'unsafe-eval' for a 'script-src' policy, but only for a specific domain.
>   How can I achieve this behavior?

You can’t. Content Security Policy doesn’t provide a way to do that.

Both `'unsafe-eval'` and `*.example.net` are just different types of what the CSP spec calls a *“source expression”*, and the values of CSP directives such as `script-src` are what the CSP spec calls *“source lists”* — lists of separate individual source expressions.

And source expressions in a CSP source list have no internal association with each other — instead they each apply *globally* to the directive they’re associated with.

So if you specify `'unsafe-eval'` for the value of a `script-src` directive, then that always has the effect of globally allowing `eval()` in any JavaScript code in the document relies on.

There is no other syntax in CSP to express *“only allow `'unsafe-eval'` for `*.example.net`”*. There’s just no way to express that in CSP.

---

From https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#framework-directive-source-list:

> Many directives' values consist of ***source lists***: sets of strings which identify content that can be fetched and potentially embedded or executed. Each string represents one of the following types of ***source expression***:
>
> 1. Keywords such as `'none'` and `'self`' (which match nothing and the current URL’s origin, respectively)
> 2. Serialized URLs such as `https://example.com/path/to/file.js` (which matches a specific file) or `https://example.com/` (which matches everything on that origin)
> 3. Schemes such as `https:` (which matches any resource having the specified scheme)
> 4. Hosts such as `example.com` (which matches any resource on the host, regardless of scheme) or `*.example.com` (which matches any resource on the host’s subdomains (and any of its subdomains' subdomains, and so on))
> 5. Nonces such as `'nonce-ch4hvvbHDpv7xCSvXCs3BrNggHdTzxUA'` (which can match specific elements on a page)
> 6. Digests such as `'sha256-abcd...'` (which can match specific elements on a page)

Comment: so we can't allow unsafe-inline for particular domain  and rest all with self?